# Removing duplication sub-strings separated by semicolon from the string

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have an excel file in which one column has strings. I am trying to remove duplicate sub-strings separated by semicolon & space ("; "). But the code throwing errors. Input and output requires as follows:

**Input**

> ABC, Bhubaneswar, India; DEF, Bhubaneswar, India; ABC, Bhubaneswar,India
> GHR, Bhubaneswar, India; ABC, Bhubaneswar, India
> DEF,Bhubaneswar, India; DEF, Bhubaneswar, India
> GHR, Bhubaneswar, India

**Output**

> ABC, Bhubaneswar, India; DEF, Bhubaneswar, India
> GHR, Bhubaneswar, India; ABC, Bhubaneswar, India
> DEF, Bhubaneswar, India
> GHR, Bhubaneswar, India

```
import pandas as pd
pipe_data = pd.read_excel('/content/sample_data/aff.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')
df = pd.DataFrame(pipe_data)
df['RepStr'] = df['RepStr'].str.split("; ")
df['RepStr'] = df['RepStr'].apply(lambda x: set(map(str.strip , x)))
df['RepStr']
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: `----> 6 df['RepStr'] = df['RepStr'].apply(lambda x: set(map(str.strip , x)))`
      

**TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable**

Comment: Something is odd with your input or output or description. Splitting your input at `"; "` results in 5 __different__ strings, i.e., `1. ABC, Bhubaneswar, India, 2. DEF, Bhubaneswar, India ABC, Bhubaneswar, India, 3. GHR,Bhubaneswar, India, 4. ABC, Bhubaneswar, India DEF, Bhubaneswar, India and 5. DEF,Bhubaneswar, India GHR, Bhubaneswar, India`. There are no duplicates. This is not the reason for the error, but to help you, one needs to know what you're looking for. Can you please check your input and desired output (and description)? Also does `df['RepStr']` has non-`str`s, e.g., `float`s?

Comment: Also does the ordering of the substrings (and the words that make up the substring) matter? If yes, in the input, output, in both?

Comment: @NikolaosChatzis Kindly check the input and output again. There was some mix-up before since I had not included <br> . I need "the ordering of the substrings"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little modification my following code is working fine:

```
import pandas as pd
pipe_data = pd.read_excel('/content/sample_data/aff.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')
df = pd.DataFrame(pipe_data)
df.dropna(inplace = True)
df['RepStr'] = df['RepStr'].str.split("; ")
df['RepStr'] = df['RepStr'].map(pd.unique).str.join("; ")
with pd.ExcelWriter('/content/sample_data/aff.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you have in your input are the strings in the column of interest of 4 rows. You can remove the duplicate substrings as follows:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Dummy' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'RepStr' : ['ABC, Bhubaneswar, India; DEF, Bhubaneswar, India; ABC, Bhubaneswar, India', 'GHR, Bhubaneswar, India; ABC, Bhubaneswar, India', 'DEF, Bhubaneswar, India; DEF, Bhubaneswar, India', 'GHR, Bhubaneswar, India']})
>>>
>>> with pd.option_context(
...     'display.width', None, 
...     'display.max_columns', None, 
...     'display.max_colwidth', -1, 
...     'display.colheader_justify', 'left'):
...     print(df)
... 
  Dummy RepStr                                                                    
0  a     ABC, Bhubaneswar, India; DEF, Bhubaneswar, India; ABC, Bhubaneswar, India
1  b     GHR, Bhubaneswar, India; ABC, Bhubaneswar, India                         
2  c     DEF, Bhubaneswar, India; DEF, Bhubaneswar, India                         
3  d     GHR, Bhubaneswar, India 
>>>
>>> df['RepStr'] = df['RepStr'].apply(lambda x: '; '.join(dict.fromkeys((x.split('; ')))))
>>>
>>> with pd.option_context(
...      'display.width', None, 
...      'display.max_columns', None,
...      'display.max_colwidth', -1, 
...      'display.colheader_justify', 'left'):
...     print(df)
... 
  Dummy RepStr                                           
0  a     ABC, Bhubaneswar, India; DEF, Bhubaneswar, India
1  b     GHR, Bhubaneswar, India; ABC, Bhubaneswar, India
2  c     DEF, Bhubaneswar, India                         
3  d     GHR, Bhubaneswar, India
```

A few points to note:

- I used `dict.fromkeys()` instead of `set()` because the former in Python 3.6 and above respects the insert order, whereas the latter not. If you do not care about the order of the substrings you can use `set()`. Also if your Python version is not 3.6 and above and the order of the substrings is important you may want to consider an `OrderedDict`.
- Your input example still has some issues that make the strings different, e.g., note in the first row `ABC, Bhubaneswar, India` is not `ABC, Bhubaneswar,India` (there is a space missing in the latter). From your output example, I assume that you wanted them to be the same string.
- The `with` piece does not add anything to the solution. I included it just for illustration purposes; so that the rows fit in the screen.

Comment: It is throwing an error "'float' object is not iterable" since the input is from an excel file. Where to include the "for loop" so that it will read & write cell by cell